# Using REGEXP vs IN on a subquery mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to use the data from table 'similar' to find results from table 'releases'

Table 'Similar' has this structure

```
artist  similar_artist
Moodymann   Theo Parrish
Moodymann   Jeff Mills
Moodymann   Marcellus Pittman
Moodymann   Rick Wilhite
```

My query so far is

```
SELECT * FROM releases
WHERE 
releases.all_artists REGEXP 'Moodymann'
OR releases.label_no_country='KDJ'
OR releases.all_artists IN (SELECT similar_artist 
                            FROM similar 
                            WHERE artist='Moodymann')
ORDER BY date DESC
```

the column 'all_artists' has records like this:

```
Moodymann | Theo Parrish | Rick Wade
Jeff Mills | Moodymann | Rick Wilhite
```

So the end query that I want will essentially be this

```
SELECT * FROM releases
    WHERE 
    releases.all_artists REGEXP 'Moodymann'
    OR releases.label_no_country='KDJ'
    OR releases.all_artists IN ('Theo Parrish','Jeff Mills','Marcellus Pittman','Rick Wilhite')
```

To make matches I think I need to use REGEXP instead of IN - REGEXP returns the 'Subquery returns more than 1 row'. How can use the data returned from the subquery?

Also the query is taking a long time to run (up to 20 seconds) - is there anyway to speed this up as this is not usable in my web app.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you don't need the third condition as it is already met by first one. So i would suggest to remove releases.all_artists IN (SELECT similar_artist FROM similar WHERE artist='Moodymann')

Comment: I want to use the in the similar artists, hence the use of the subquery :)

Comment: So you want to compare something like this ? Moodymann | Theo Parrish | Rick Wade IN('Theo Parrish,Jeff Mills,Marcellus Pittman,Rick Wilhite') ????

Comment: The query on all_artists will not use an index and will likely be very slow. Better to split that off onto a separate table with multiple rows, then you can do a simple join.

Comment: **You have to refactor (normalize) your schema**. Trying to store list of artists in one column is just asking for trouble long term.

Answer (score 4):

The only way I would know of how to use REGEXP with a subquery, would be to use that subquery to produce a REGEXP string.

```
SELECT * FROM releases
WHERE 
releases.all_artists REGEXP 'Moodymann'
OR releases.label_no_country='KDJ'
OR releases.all_artists REGEXP (
   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(similar_artist SEPARATOR '|') 
   FROM similar 
   WHERE artist='Moodymann' 
   GROUP BY similar_artist)
ORDER BY date DESC
```

The above isn't tested, is just a theory to what I might try. It's not going to be very optimal however.

#### update

Have since tested this and found that `GROUP BY similar_artist` should be `GROUP BY artist`

```
SELECT * FROM releases
WHERE 
releases.all_artists REGEXP 'Moodymann'
OR releases.label_no_country='KDJ'
OR releases.all_artists REGEXP (
   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(similar_artist SEPARATOR '|') 
   FROM similar 
   WHERE artist='Moodymann' 
   GROUP BY artist)
ORDER BY date DESC
```

However, as mentioned by Pheonix you would be better off refactoring your structure to have a `releases_artist` table. You could then do all this work via JOINs which would be much, much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL

```
SELECT * 
FROM releases
WHERE releases.all_artists LIKE '%Moodymann%'
OR releases.label_no_country='KDJ'
ORDER BY date DESC
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/467626/1)

**MySQL 5.5.30 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`artist` varchar(9), `similar_artist` varchar(17))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`artist`, `similar_artist`)
VALUES
    ('Moodymann', 'Theo Parrish'),
    ('Moodymann', 'Jeff Mills'),
    ('Moodymann', 'Marcellus Pittman'),
    ('Moodymann', 'Rick Wilhite')
;


create table allt(allf varchar(50));

insert into allt values('Moodymann | Theo Parrish | Rick Wade'),
('Jeff Mills | Moodymann | Rick Wilhite'),
('Jeff Mills | asdasdadasd | Rick Wilhite');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM allt
WHERE allt.allf LIKE '%Moodymann%'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/467626/1/0)**:

```
|                                  ALLF |
-----------------------------------------
|  Moodymann | Theo Parrish | Rick Wade |
| Jeff Mills | Moodymann | Rick Wilhite |
```

Comment: I want to use the in the similar artists, hence the use of the subquery :)

Comment: @Franco : You need to normalize your database in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a join on a comma separated list (won't be fast, but might be quicker than using LIKE with a leading wild card), and you can replace your existing delimiter with a comma to allow this. Also you can use a load of UNIONs to get your list of artists to behave like a table to do a join on.

Further you can use union instead of your other WHERE clauses which might well help with allowing the use of indexes (MySQL will only use one index per table in a query, hence using OR to query on a different column forces it to not use an index for one of the columns it is checking).

As such you can do something like the following:-

```
SELECT releases.* 
FROM releases
INNER JOIN (SELECT 'Theo Parrish' AS anArtist UNION SELECT 'Jeff Mills' UNION SELECT 'Marcellus Pittman' UNION SELECT 'Rick Wilhite') Sub1
ON FIND_IN_SET(Sub1.anArtist, REPLACE(releases.all_artists, " | ", ",")) > 0
UNION
SELECT releases.* 
FROM releases
WHERE releases.label_no_country='KDJ'
```

However if changing the database design to split the pipe separated list of artists onto a different table is even a slight option then do that instead. It will be far quicker and will cope with far greater numbers of artists.